# Excel 2016 Too Many Arguments Error Message

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel 2016: I am trying to get two columns that, when entered need to produce a "1" or true value that is formatted to highlights under a corresponding year and quarter. This means there are two dates per row.

The way I enter the formula, returns with an error message that I entered too many arguments. Could someone please provide some insight on what I may be doing wrong?

Here is a copy of the formula: `=IF(OR(AND($O3>=DATE(2019,1,1),$O3<=DATE(2019,3,31)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2019,4,1),$R3<=DATE(2019,6,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2019,7,1),$R3<=DATE(2019,9,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2019,10,1),$R3<=DATE(2019,12,31)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2020,1,1),$R3<=DATE(2020,3,31)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2020,4,1),$R3<=DATE(2020,6,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2020,7,1),$R3<=DATE(2020,9,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2020,10,1),$R3<=DATE(2020,12,31)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2021,1,1),$R3<=DATE(2021,3,31)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2021,4,1),$R3<=DATE(2021,6,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2021,7,1),$R3<=DATE(2021,9,30)),1,0,IF(AND($R3>=DATE(2021,10,1),$R3<=DATE(2021,12,31)),1,0))))))))))))`

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1409953/edit) to provide sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: You have one more `(` than `)` for a start ...

Comment: This formula needs to be rewritten from the ground up IMO. `=IF(OR(AND($O3>=DATE(2019,1,1),$O3<=DATE(2019,3,31)),1,0,` and I can stop you there. In other words `IF(OR(AND(test1,test2),1,0` ... which evaluates to... `IF(OR(test1,1,0`... it doesn't matter what comes next

Comment: "The way I enter the formula, returns with an error message that I entered too many arguments. Could someone please provide some insight on what I may be doing wrong?" - Yes, you have too many arguments...

Comment: Some techniques when troubleshooting a formula. Expand the formula bar by dragging its bottom edge down. Insert line breaks at meaningful intervals using <Alt>-<Enter>. Add a space after open parenthesis unless there is only one short argument like a range. Add a space after commas. Add a space on either side of an operator "a<=b" is "a <= b". While in the formula bar, use the arrow keys to move the cursor back and forth over a parenthesis until the matching parenthesis flicker is identified. View the formula tooltip below the formula bar to identify the innermost function at the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good bunch of nested functions.

The hard part here is to keep track of the closing parentheses.

My advice: If you absolutely cannot rewrite the formula with less complex statements, then use a text editor that helps you keep track of opening and closing brace/parentheses.

Editors: Notepad++, Geany and similar.